# Real analysis Math

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

> Prove the following:
>
> Let $T$ be the linear operator from the normed space $X$ over $\mathbb{R}$ to the normed space $Y$ over $\mathbb{R}$. If $T$ is continuous on unit ball ($B(0,1)$) of $X$, then $T$ is continuous on $X$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: What is your definition of continuity?

Comment: Hint: Use continuity of $T$ like this: $$||Tx-Tx_0|| = ||T(x-x_0) - T(0)|| < \epsilon$$ ... Can you continue?

Comment: Write T(0) beacaus unit ball ??

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0 \in X$ and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ with $x_n \to x_0$. Then

$z_n:= x_n - x_0 \to 0$. Hence there ist $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $z_n \in B(0,1)$ for $n > N$. Since $T$ is continuous in $0$, we get $Tz_n \to T0=0$, hence

$Tx_n \to Tx_0$.